# INTEL HEX file error , " CR or CR/LF " expected

Tags: simulation, hex-file

I'm trying to write a INTEL HEX file for chip 2732 . 
My hex file data is here :

:03000000201C5D64

:0300FF00201C5D65

but when I start simulation , proteus shows this error:
[image]

I have a little idea what this CR or CR/LF means but can't figure out how to implement this in my file.If I give " Enter " at the end of the second line  it also gives error like " colon expected at the starting of the line " . There is no check sum error.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: -1.  Did something prevent you from using this very same Internet to look-up what CR and LF are?

Comment: I search and still searching in the internet. I get the idea about CR and LF but still can't solve my problem. So I posted this here and thought this may mean different thing. Sorry if my question seems too childish.

Comment: Ah!Ahh! After checksum! It's not the ends of lines it's complaining about, it's the end of file. Have you omitted a final cr/lf after the checksum at the end of the file?

Comment: yeah , that was my error.I just learning from internet how to write hex file and this thing slipped by me :/  my bad .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was missing the last line of the INTEL HEX file format. 
we have to write :

:01000001FF

at the end of every file. This indicates "End of file " . other wise it seems like , this file is not ended .

Answer (score 1):

CR is Carriage Return, and LF is Line Feed.  These characters are used to terminate a line in a text file.

An Intel Hex file should have a CR character (or CR/LF pair) at the end of each line of hex data - just before the colon in your example.

When viewed in a text editor, your data should look like:

```
:03000000201C5D64
:0300FF00201C5D65
```

Comment: My text editor looks like just like you. Where do you put CR ?
if I give "enter" at the end of second line, this also gives a error.

Comment: Have you got a single LF character at the ends of your lines? Many editors will display nice lines like you see in that case. You need to have a look at the characters in your file without a text editor translating them to what it thinks you mean. Try frhed (free hex editor) to see what they really are.